# Webdriver: expose selector/by/location of existing element

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

### The problem:

.Click()-ing a radio button webdriver element stales it(no control over the page that does this). The DOM element itself is still the same.

### The goal:

I want to reset the existing webdriver element using its own original selector method so that it is no longer stale. I want a general solution that does not require knowing ahead of time how the element was found. I want to use the existing stale element to do the work. Ideal case would look something like this(using the following C# extension method just for sake of example):

```
IWebElement refreshedElement = driver.FindElement(staleElement.By());
```

### The question:

Is there a way to expose the existing elements location? Is the 'address' of the element available anywhere? It doesn't even have to be the original method of addressing the element when it was found, I don't care about that. I'd just rather not have to make a subclass just to capture this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Selenium does not keep track of 'how' you found an element, and frankly I don't think that should be Selenium's responsibility.

I would wrap it into a new class, which inherits from `RemoteWebElement`, and has a method called `RefindElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest considering adding the concept of a "Page Class".  Basically, instead of adding the element to the test itself, I create a separate class that has methods that return elements.

For example, a login page would have three elements therefore 3 methods:

```
public class LoginPage
{
    private IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
    public CSCView_SalesAspx(IWebDriver driver) { this.driver = driver; }

    public IWebElement Id { get { return driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_id")); } }
    public IWebElement Pw { get { return driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_pw")); } }
    public IWebElement SubmitBtn { get { return driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitBtn")); } }
}
```

Now all you have to do is instantiate the class then interact with the method.  Your element should always be "fresh" since you're doing the lookup every time (without any extra work).

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
loginPage.Id.SendKeys("myName");
loginPage.Pw.SendKeys("myPw");
loginPage.SubmitBtn.Click();
```

The best thing about this is if a page changes, instead of having to rewrite every test, you only change one page class and that fixes your broken tests.